# How do I set AG-Grid's height to automatically match the data content height?

Tags: angular6, ag-grid

I'm trying to get ag-grid's height to match the content.

I have several sets of data which I'm trying to load into different grids, each with the appropriate height for the data.

There is an AutoHeight option but the Angular version doesn't seem to work (I'm assuming this is for a previous version).

Here is my alternative attempt, which doesn't work:

```
                <ng-container *ngFor="let reportItem of reportData">
                    <br />
                    <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: {{ 560 + (reportItem.data.length * 40) }}px;"
                                     class="ag-theme-material bold-headers"
                                     [rowData]="reportItem.data"
                                     [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
                    </ag-grid-angular>
                </ng-container>
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Rather than just linking to the Auto-Grid Height method I described at the top - which I tried and failed with, could you please explain how I should implement it with my code above? (as I accept I may have missed something)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#auto-height) you can use `domLayout='autoHeight'` as a property to your grid.

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `setGridAutoHeight` method available on the `api` object. You need to get a reference to that object from the `gridReady` event and then you can call it, passing `true` to it. You have to take care with it if your data has many rows because using this method all the rows will be rendered to the DOM, normally only the visible ones are rendered.

`gridApi.setGridAutoHeight(true)`

It's at the bottom of the page: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/

Comment: I get `Property 'setGridAutoHeight' does not exist on type 'GridApi'`

Comment: I use AgGrid in Vue.js and it works well on my side. I suppose you must be using TypeScript inside Angular. Try to find the method in the grid api object directly then I think you must declare it in the TypeScript type declarations file.

Comment: No looks like it isn't part of the api at all, even though it's in the documentation - although there isn't actually any Angular specific documentation, it all just links to the javascript docs.

Comment: What is the difference between using this and setting domLayout='autoHeight' ? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#auto-height

Comment: @Chris Looks similar. I am not sure, maybe one is older than another. Can't recommend on over the other.

Comment: You can set it like so: gridApi.setGridOption('domLayout', 'autoHeight');